# Vector Addition -- Direction

Tags: forces, vectors, notation

Say we have three forces $F_1, F_2, F_3$, such that

$$
F_1 + F_2 - F_3 = 0\hspace 10mm (1)
$$

And let us say that $F_1$ and $F_2$ have the same direction and magnitude, and that $F_3$ has double the magnitude of either, in the opposite direction.

From this it would seem that $F_1$ and $F_2$ had the same direction (in highschool physics, at least!), but if we treat these vectors like numbers, we can make another statement:

$$
F_1 - F_3 = - F_2\hspace 10mm (2)
$$

And yet this seems absurd to me, since equality of vectors seems to imply equality of direction. From the statement in $(1)$ I can also state that:
$$
F_1 = F_2\hspace 10mm (3)
$$

But this contradicts $(2)$!

Edit: So they don't contradict, but I guess what I was wondering was the *notation* -- that is, if we say that there is a force $F = ma$, $F - ma = 0$ follows. Does this mean that $ma$ and $F$ are in opposite directions? What does the negative sign really mean?

I'm sure I've probably totally missed the point of vectors, but I can't seem to be able to contract this question into a Google search.

Comment: How do you get (3) from (1)? It does not follow. There is no reason for $F_1$ and $F_2$ to be in the same direction, and equation (2) is perfectly fine. Does [this](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/vect.html) help?

Comment: Your first assumption is wrong. $F_1 + F_2 - F_3=0$ never implies $F_1$ and $F_2$ are in the same direction. You can definitely add forces in different directions and the fact that their sum is zero means you can construct a triangle with these vectors (adjust the direction accordingly). Check this link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector#Addition_and_subtraction

Comment: @MichaelBrown I don't know, if two vectors have the same direction and magnitude, should they not equate?

Comment: @Debangshu, I'm aware of that, but what of the case where $F1$ and $F2$ are of the same direction? $(1)$ still holds, no?

Comment: Yes, they may be in the same direction but, nothing can be said about the magnitude and there is no way you can write Equation (3) from Equation (1) even if they are in the same direction. As you yourself pointed out, vector equality will hold if both magnitude and direction are the same.

Comment: @Debangshu, yes but say $F_1$ and $F_2$ have the same direction and magnitude, and $F_3$ had double their magnitude, and in the opposite direction. $(1)$ would hold, and by subtraction $(2)$ seems to be logically correct. But then $(3)$ would also be true based on what I said about $(1)$, which seems to confuse me.

Comment: if $F_1 = F_2$, it means $F_3 = 2F_1$. So, equation (2) is $F_1 -F_3 = F_1 - 2F_1 = -F_1$. Now, since $F_1 = F_2$, we can also write $-F_1 = -F_2$ which proves the second statement: $F_1-F_3 = -F_2$ and hence there is no contradiction between (2) and (3).

Comment: So if I wanted to describe a system of forces and wrote $F_1$ + $F_2$ = $F_3$, $F_3$ is in the opposite direction as $F_1$? But then what about $\Sigma F = ma$? with subtraction we'd say they have opposite directions, but then, they don't right?

Comment: $F_3$ will be in a direction opposite to $F_1$ ONLY IF $F_2$ is in SAME DIRECTION as $F_1$ or else in general NO.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8071/discussion-between-soyuz-and-debangshu)

Comment: @Soyuz I see where you are getting hung up. $-F$ has the opposite direction as $F$. From equation (1) $F_3$ is in the *same* direction as $F_1 + F_2$, not the opposite direction.

Comment: @MichaelBrown, I think I've sorted it out. I think this all arose from a misunderstanding from a physics book thing. Must've been a typo. Thanks though!

Comment: @Soyuz, please clean up your question then or remove it alltogether.

Comment: @user9886: It's not really a bad question, why should he remove it?

Comment: @Manishearth: As it stands now it contains contradictory statements. Maybe it is enough to edit the question accordingly or include a reference to the last comment by Michael Brown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So to address your 2nd question regarding $F = ma$ and its simple transformation through subtraction $ F - ma = 0$.  In this case $\vec F$ and $\vec a$ are vectors, $m$ is simply a scalar multiplier on $a$ that is along for the ride.  When you subtract one vector from another this requires that you flip the direction of the vector in order to do the subtraction, thus if the two vectors are equal you'll get $\vec 0$ as the result.

Really this isn't an different than scalar subtraction if you have $x = y$, then $x-y = 0$.